# C struct type not found including library, error "unknown type name"

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, include

I didn't find a solution to a very simple problem.

File "commons.h":

```
struct test_struct{
   int a;
}
```

File "work.c":

```
#include "commons.h"
void myfunction(test_struct this_is_a_test){
// ....
}
```

what I do:

```
gcc commons.c -c -o commons.o    (no errors)
gcc work.c -c -o work.o ( "unknown type name "test_struct")
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have also another .c which include "commons.h" and while compiling everything is fine, only with work.c I get error.

Comment: this struct definition: `struct test_struct{
   int a;
}` is missing the trailing semicolon: `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header file only defines `struct test_struct`, not `test_struct`. You need a `typedef` so you can refer to it without saying `struct` first.

```
typedef struct test_struct {
    int a;
} test_struct;
```

Or change `work.c` to use `struct`.

```
void myfunction(struct test_struct this_is_a_test) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: this solved. Why do I have problem without typedef?

Comment: Because that's how the C language works. Defining a structure doesn't create a new type name, you have to use `typedef` to create a type that's a synonym for the structure type.

Comment: If you're used to C++, it does this automatically, but C doesn't work the same.

Comment: I missunderstood the meaning of "new type", now I got it